# Replacing part of an ID

Tags: jquery, string, replace

I'm having trouble trying to replace a specific part of an ID for all the elements on my page with a specific class. The id's are dynamically generated when the page loads (come from a database) so I can't hardcode the values I need to replace.

For example, I'll have something like this:

```
<div id="BUL_123" class="commentary_list_item newItem">
  <span id="commentary_list_text_123" class="removableItem newItem">
    <img id="added_cancelIcon_123" class="cancelIcon newItem" src="delete_icon.gif">
  </span>
</div>
```

And I want to replace all of the "123"s with some other id but keep the "BUL_", "commentary_list_text_", "added_cancelIcon_" parts.

I can get the 123 value with a split function but I'm not sure how to replace them on my page.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

SOLUTION:

```
function ReplaceIDNumber(data, id) {

 jQuery('.newItem').each(function() {

    var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    var id_split = el_id.split('_');

    newID = id.replace(id_split[id_split.length - 1], data);
    jQuery(this).attr('id', newID);
});
```

(the "data" comes from the ajax call I make that directs to this function)

Thanks for all the help and sorry about the vagueness of the question

Comment: What do you want to replace them with?

Comment: Show the code you have so far.

Comment: simple logic would be to extract the complete html code in the body as a text using `.text ()` in variable. and then replace the specfic word with the new word using `.replace(from,to)`.

Comment: I want to replace them with a different Id I get from an AJAX call that hits the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some good answers, but they all assume something - so some more information would be helpful.  I'll assume: (1) The last part (as separated by "_") is what needs to be replaced (2) The last part will not always be 123

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // all id
  var $allIds = $('[id]');
  var $this;
  var id;
  var idArray;
  var idArrayLength;
  var newId;

  $allIds.each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    id = $this.attr('id');
    idArray = id.split("_");
    idArrayLength = idArray.length;
    newId = id.replace(idArray[idArrayLength-1], "abc");
    $this.attr('id', newId);
  })
})
```

Comment: I ended up using a little from a couple different answers but this one helped me the most. I edited the question with my solution

Answer (score 3):

You can use `attr`/`prop`'s callback function and `replace` method:

```
$('#wrapper [id$="123"]').attr('id', function(_, currentID) {
   return currentID.replace('123', '321');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PZ9vB/

Comment: Each ID # is dynamically generated so I can't hardcode 123. That's the part i'm having trouble with. Should have added that, my bad

Answer (score 0):

Without a better definition of the problem, you can replace the numerical part of the id with this regex:

```
var str = "BUL_123";
str.replace(/\d+/,"foo");
```

This will replace `123` with `foo` (substitute whatever you want to replace it with). This works so long as the prefix part doesn't also contain numbers. If that's the case, then you need to get a little more creative.